# Play three audio in sequence and collect response javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, sequence

I'd like to know whether it's possible to play three audio files one after the other and having a participant clicking on a button (perhaps a speech bubble) indicating the audio file he wants to select. Everything while an image is displayed constantly at the bottom (or top I really don't care about that).

IMPORTANT: I'd like each audio + speech bubble to appear together one at a time and stay on the monitor until the last sound has been played.

I have a drawing of what I mean:

[image]

A plus is to make it possible with some jsPsych plugin!
Please help me guys!

---

UPDATE, problem solved ! 
The main idea is to give up on the for loop, or providing a whole vector ideas and specify each audio as an independent trial, and concatenate the trials into a bigger "task". 
The solution came from the main [JsPsych](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jspsych/KVeAbrJc8As) group.

```
experiment: [];
    var trial1 = {
    type: 'audio-button-response',
    stimulus: 'audio1.mp3',
    choices: ['img/speech.png', 'img/speech.png', 'img/speech.png'],
        trial_ends_after_audio: true,
        prompt: "<img src='stimImage.jpg'>"
};

var trial2 = {
    type: 'audio-button-response',
    stimulus: 'audio2.mp3',
    choices: ['img/speech.png', 'img/speech.png', 'img/speech.png'],
        trial_ends_after_audio: true,
    prompt: "<img src='stimImage.jpg'>"
};

var trial3 = {
    type: 'audio-button-response',
    stimulus: 'audio3.mp3',
    choices: ['img/speech.png', 'img/speech.png', 'img/speech.png'],
        response_ends_trial: true,
        prompt: "<img src='stimImage.jpg'>",
        on_finish: function(data) {
        jsPsych.data.addDataToLastTrial({
          key_press: data.choices
        });
      },
};


var fixation_trial = {
  type: 'html-keyboard-response',
  stimulus: '<div style="font-size:60px;">+</div>',
  choices: [69],
  trial_duration: 1000, 
  data: {
    test_part: 'fixation cross'
  },
  on_finish: function(data) {
    if (data.key_press == 69) { //press letter 'e' to skip this part
      jsPsych.endCurrentTimeline();
    }
  }
};

var task = {
  timeline: [fixation_trial, trial1, trial2, trial3]
};
experiment.push(task);
jsPsych.init({
timeline: experiment,
})
```

Comment: It certainly is possible. Show us what you've made so far and we'll help you out.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier done! let me know

Answer (score 0):

Although the examples of jsPsych about audio are not abundant, I did manage to find [this example](https://www.jspsych.org/core_library/jspsych-core/#jspsychendcurrenttimeline) which loops images until a button is pushed and implemented the same logic to your audio files.

I'm not sure if the speech bubbles will appear at the correct moment, but altering the object in the `audio_trials.push()` method to include each image with each audio file, might solve it.

```
var audio = ['dep.mp3', 'dep.mp3', 'dep.mp3'];

var audio_trials = [];
for (let i = 0; i < audio.length; i++) {
  audio_trials.push({
    stimulus: audio[i]
  });
}

var audio_trial = {
  type: 'audio-button-response',
  choices: ['img/speech.png', 'img/speech.png', 'img/speech.png'],
  prompt: "<p>Click on the correct speech bubble</p>",
  button_html: '<img src="%choice%" style="width: 300px"/>',
  on_finish: function(data) {
    jsPsych.data.addDataToLastTrial({
      key_press: data.choices
    });
  },
  timeline: audio_trials
};

var fixation_trial = {
  type: 'html-keyboard-response',
  stimulus: '<div style="font-size:60px;">+</div>',
  choices: [69],
  trial_duration: 1000, // here there is the random variation
  data: {
    test_part: 'fixation cross'
  },
  on_finish: function(data) {
    if (data.key_press == 69) { //press letter 'e' to skip this part
      jsPsych.endCurrentTimeline();
    }
  }
};

jsPsych.init({
  timeline: [fixation_trial, audio_trial],
  use_webaudio: true
});
```

Comment: Hi Emiel, Thanks a lot, on line 8 there it an extra ), and in jsPsych.init() you shoudl add jsPsych.init(timeline: trials), anyway once you've correct these details the task works exactly like before: it plays only one audio and doesn't throw any error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed the typo's. I'm afraid that my knowledge of this framework is too limited to get you where you need to go. Maybe someone can help you on a forum like [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jspsych/3RQIsIFWBaU).

Comment: Thanks! no solution so far also from that group. If I get something to work I'll update the post, thanks a lot!